# How can i solve this system of 3 linear differential equation?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Consider the following system of differential equations given below
$$\begin{cases} \ x'_1(t)=3x_1(t)+x_2(t)+x_3(t)  \quad . ...(1)\\ x'_2(t)=2x_1(t)+4x_2(t)+2x_3(t) \quad . ...(2) \\ x'_3(t)=-x_1(t)-x_2(t)+x_3(t) \quad . ...(3)
 \end{cases}$$
Where $x_i(t)$ is real valued differential function of real variable $t$ for all $i$. Determine all the solutions of the system of differential equations.

My attempt:
From first equation I got $$x_3=x'_1-3x_1-x_2\tag 4$$
differentiating (4), I got $$x'_3=x''_1-3x_1-x'_2\tag 5$$
plugging in from (4) into (2) above, i got
$$x'_2=2x'_1-4x_1+2x_2\tag 6$$
plugging in from (5) into (3) above, I got
$$-x'_2+x''_1-4x'_1+4x_1+2x_2=0\tag 7$$
Adding (6) and (7), i got
$$x''_1-6x'_1+8x_1=0\tag 8$$
Now, I can solve ODE given by (8) easily.

My question:
is there a simple or direct method to get all three O.D.E. in terms of $x''_1, x''_2$ & $x''_3$ ?

Please help me by giving easiest method to solve system of three linear O.D.E.. Thanks

Comment: You can use matrix exponentials to get the solution of the first order system, it does not make sense to move to derivatives of order 2. All solutions are linear combinations of $e^{2t}$ and $e^{4t}$.

Comment: How? please help

Comment: The solution of a system of differential equations of the form $x' = Ax$ is given by $x = e^{t A} x_0$.

Comment: Can you please give answer showing some steps for above problem?

Answer (score 1):

The system is in the form $x' = Ax$, with the matrix $A$ being of the form
$$
A = \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\-2 & 0 & 1\\ 1&1 &0
 \end{pmatrix}}_{=S}
\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
4 & 0 &0\\ 0 & 2 & 0\\0 & 0& 2
\end{pmatrix}}_{=~\Lambda}
\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & -1 & -1 \\-2 & 0 & 1\\ 1&1 &0
 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

You can reach this conclusion by computing eigenvalues and eigenvectors. Now,
$$
e^{t \Lambda} = \begin{pmatrix}
e^{4t}& 0 &0\\0& e^{2t}&0\\0 & 0 & e^{2t} 
\end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
e^{tA} = S e^{t \Lambda} S^{-1} = \left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \frac{e^{2 t}}{2}+\frac{e^{4 t}}{2} & \frac{e^{4 t}}{2}-\frac{e^{2 t}}{2} & \frac{e^{4
   t}}{2}-\frac{e^{2 t}}{2} \\
 e^{4 t}-e^{2 t} & e^{4 t} & e^{4 t}-e^{2 t} \\
 \frac{e^{2 t}}{2}-\frac{e^{4 t}}{2} & \frac{e^{2 t}}{2}-\frac{e^{4 t}}{2} & \frac{3 e^{2
   t}}{2}-\frac{e^{4 t}}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The solution to the system of equations is simply $x = e^{tA} x_0$, where $x_0$ corresponds to the initial condition.

Comment: How did you get matrix S and A?

Comment: Please elaborate a little more. I am a beginner so please help me

Comment: Matrix $A$ comes from the system, matrix $\Lambda$  has the eigenvalues of $A$ and matrix $S$ contains the eigenvectors (in columns)

Comment: @ShivaVenkata You must really read through some elementary text on the subject (like the ones suggested in the comments to your post). There are several possible situations to consider that you cannot see in this particular example.